# How can I get SharePoint server datetime using CSOM model?

Tags: c#, rest, sharepoint, csom

I'm creating a service that will notify people about new tasks in SharePoint. For this I have to somehow get it's server datetime due to a huge desynchronisation gaps in time value when comparing it to datetime.now result.

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint store datetime as UTC time, so try to use [TimeZone.UTCToLocalTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-csom/jj164700(v%3Doffice.15))。

```
var localTime = context.Web.RegionalSettings.TimeZone.UTCToLocalTime((DateTime)listItem.FieldValues["Created"]);
                context.ExecuteQuery();
                Console.WriteLine(localTime.Value);
```